# CSV import ends up in unresolvable state

Tags: feeds, commerce

I'm having a problem with Feeds and Commerce Feeds in D7.

I am using Feeds and Commerce Feeds to import products into my Drupal Commerce store.

The CSV import was failing with a 403 error. Once this happened the import button was greyed out with text showing "importing 21% complete". Initially I cleared the message by running a delete and then reuploading. Now the delete tab has the same problem! It says "deleting 51% complete"

I have added a [support request](http://drupal.org/node/1216018) for this on drupal.org; but I think that the question may be better suited here as a "how-to" type answer would seem more appropriate.

Any ideas on how I can sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by cloning my import.

When I selected the cloned import it wasn't hampered by the progress information and greyed out import button. I could just upload my csv via the new import.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same case, I just delete the imported item then import button enabled again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @monymirza I believe that was a honest attempt to answer. sibiru, could you try to avoid sentences looking like "me too" posts? And elaborate a bit, ie where and what exactly you deleted (ie URL to proper admin page, with site changed to example.com )?